# I can't access URL on my own server, but others can

Tags: nat

I have a server running webcams at 96.30.159.42:8081.  If YOU click on this address you will see the 3 cameras I have set up.

If I enter that address (or click on they hyperlink on my webpage), NOTHING happens.  I don't get re-directed, no activity icon, no error.  NO ACCESS.  Of course I had access at one time.

Can't see anything in my DIR655 router that is preventing access.  Can't see any firewall block either (but maybe I'm not looking at the right option...).

Comment: Have you looked at your `hosts` file?

Comment: Did you setup (in the router) the internal server as a "Virtual Server" or did you just try to use "Port Forwarding"?  I believe it has to be setup as a Virtual Server for the NAT loopback (accessing the external IP from inside the LAN) to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: it is because my ISP doesn't allow loop-back. In other words, you can address every other device on the internet, apart from the one you are using as a gateway.

There is no easy solution. I can look at my web-site if I use a proxy (there are many of those to choose from), but I haven't found one that allows a port specification, at least not among the free ones, so I cannot see my webcams.

So, if I want to look at my webcams, I need to use their internal address 192.168.???.???:????. If I want to check that others can see it, I log into my neighbour's WiFi (this is not a hack, but a free WiFi share service provided by the ISP that we both use).

Without this, if you still have a modem and dial-up internet access, you can use this to log in with an alternative IP address and check your camera that way.

If you come across a proxy that supports port addressing, I shall be delighted to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with a little thing called "Hairpin NAT".

See link: [Unable to outside access service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-outside-access-service-from-inside-lan)

Comment: Basically what the Above user has mentioned.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as the answer in your link implies: if you have more than one camera, or a camera and a web / FTP server, then these are on different addresses within the intranet. The router's port forwarding will route different ports to different machines, but a hosts file entry can work for only one of them. In my case I set the **hosts** entry for the public URL (eg example.com) as my web/FTP server and I have to use names like webcam1, webcam2, etc for the WebCams.