# Is my port really open?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, routing

Let's say I want to have a server on my computer at port 1234, so that other hosts on the Internet can connect to it.  I am behind a router NAT, so I configure the router to forward connections to 1234 to my LAN ip address.  I use some service like [this](http://canyouseeme.org/) or [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check if it is really open, cranking in my Internet IP and port number.  It says that my port is open, and in fact at the same time the server receives a connection:

```
# nc -vv -l -p 1234
listening on [any] 1234 ...
connect to [192.168.0.7] from ec2-52-202-215-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com [52.202.215.126] 37873
sent 0, rcvd 0
```

But when I try to connect to myself with my Internet IP, it timeouts. If I do not listen on the port, the connection is simply refused, as it should be.  If I listen, it is ignored:

```
# nc -vv -l -p 1234 &
[1] 6869
# nc 95.252.xxx.xxx 1234
```

And it just hangs there.  (Of course, if I use instead the LAN IP it works fine).

Moreover, I notice that some hosts also cannot connect to my server: the original purpose of this arrangement was to quickly send commands to a friend of mine who often phones me and asks me to fix something on his computer, and who does not want to use software like telnet or ssh. Apparently also his computer cannot reach mine.

My computer does not have a firewall.  The router (as far as I know) does not filter outbound connections. (Netgear DG834G)

Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to outside access service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-outside-access-service-from-inside-lan)

Comment: So I'm unable to connect to my WAN address because of a glitch of the router.  However that doesn't explain yet why the connection times out even from my friend's computer.