# RDP work over mobile networks not from home network

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, nat

I setup one PC at remote location with the RDP connection port forwarded to 10 and changed the RDP port to 10 on PC.  I can access this PC from internet using public IP if I use the mobile internet connection.  But if I use home internet connection I am not able to get access to the PC using RDP.  not only from my home, I tried at several places and home no success at all.  but if I use my mobile phone with RDP application I can get access to the PC over public IP using RDP port 10.  I tried from various mobile network and it work.  Also if I tether my mobile network over WiFi I can use RDP from my PC or laptop without any trouble.  Only problem is not able to get the RDP from home network.  I really don't know what is the problem is.

Also, I changed the RDP port back to 3389 on the remote PC with the port forwarding to 3389 even than same issue.

Similarly, I tried web application with port 8080 the same issue.  I could always connect if I use mobile network not from home network.

Comment: I don't think that this is an information _security_ problem, at least not with only the given information. But, in case the server is in the home network (no information are provided about this) and you try to access it from the same home network using the public IP address of your router then it will not work unless your router supports [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) - some do and others don't.

Comment: I agree with Steffen - it's a router problem. There's an internal address for the server (see list of [internal IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)). You need to use that when on your internal network. Your router config will tell you the local and remote IP addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access outside service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-access-outside-service-from-inside-lan)

Comment: There's also a further discussion about whether you should expose an RDP server at all to the internet. (You shouldn't). If you can access an RDP server with no security wrapper (like a VPN), that means a potential attacker could do so and attempt to brute-force the u/p pair or use one of the many password breach files to guess your login details.