# Can't access local area server via internet IP

Tags: networking

The server has 2 IP.

```
192.168.1.30 for local area network.
220.2.2.2:8081 and http://website.com:8081 for internet visitors.
```

If I connect to 220.2.2.2:8081, it will show ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

How can I access 220.2.2.2:8081 or http://website.com:8081 like visitors? I don't want to use 192.168.1.30.
Edit my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts didn't work.

Comment: Your router has to be capable of [Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) / [NAT Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback). Not all consumer routers are capable of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access outside service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-access-outside-service-from-inside-lan)