# Can not access website on a local network, but can access from outside

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

At home I used an old PC and setup a Ubuntu 16.04 with functional Nginx server. I am hosting a website which can be reached from outside when I am not home, i.e. not using my home WiFi:

https://uhostjobs.com

Interestingly, when I am connected to VPN (given by my company), even being home and using my home WiFi the website can be reached.

Unfortunately when I am home, i.e. I am using my home WiFi then the website is not reachable. The router that I am using is Bell Home Hub 3000 and I properly setup port forwarding (saying properly since the website is functional). Previously I did the same thing with Rogers WiFi router and it was working just fine from home or from outside. But since I moved to Bell and used Bell Home Hub 3000 the problem started.

Thank you so much for your help to understand the reason why I am not able to reach the local server/website while being on local WiFi.

Advanced tools and settings:

[image: Advanced tools and settings]

Port forwarding:

[Port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfH9e.jpg)

Comment: What you need is hairpin NAT.

Comment: Hi @TwistyImpersonator, unfortunately the configuration of Bell Home Hub 3000 is very limited. I do not see anything else other than port forwarding. I added a screenshot of "Advanced tools and settings" menu of the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @G-Man for pointing to the [Unable to access outside service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-access-outside-service-from-inside-lan?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I simply added the following line to the 'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' file (first opened notepad as admin then pointed to the file):

192.168.2.17 uhostjobs.com englishrealm.net wp1.englishrealm.net

where the first number is the IP address of my Ubuntu server and then the names of the websites hosted on it. It works like a charm. I do not mind adding this file on all the computers that I will be using to connect to the server.