# My dynamic dns behaves weird

Tags: ubuntu, router, port-forwarding, remote-access, dynamic-dns

- I have builded a **raspberry pi ubuntu** all-in-one server (ftp, apache, ssh, vnc) and used dynamic dns to be able to use it remotely. When i try to connect it from **lan** ip it connects successfully from my connected phone. Also when i try connect it remotely from dynamic dns with cellular data it works great. However, in other possibilities such as wifi as lan connected phone to dyndns doesnt work and i dont know why? I have checked for if ufw is setted up but it says inactive for all. Looked at router settings, it allows lan by http and https, also wan by http and https. It doesnt block that website and also connects to router login page by wifi (lan) so there is no problem about that. **Using port forwarding**, it seems port forwarding doesn't work for some reason on lan device. By the way the error i get is **connection timed out.** Maybe it is about router settings or something else i dont know... Can you explain this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access outside service from inside LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/135366/unable-to-access-outside-service-from-inside-lan)

Comment: Yes this exactly answers (i dont know if solves not tried yet) my question. Thanks so much!